# How to trigger a graphql query (via useQuery or useLazyQuery ) when the user types text into a input text field

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to build a sort of autocomplete searchbar using GraphQL and React.
My question is: how can I manage to trigger a function that -once it checks the length of the input is bigger than 3 characters- calls one the hooks from the apollo client library (useQuery or useLazyQuery). Think that useQuery cannot be triggered inside a function or condition, I've read that for this purpose useLazyQuery can be a solution, but I do not have found any example where this situation was clearly expose.

This kind of approach I'm working on...

I have set up this function:

```
const FetchProducts = (input) => {
    
    const [getProducts,{ data, loading, error }] =  useLazyQuery(GET_PRODUCTS_QUERY, {
      variables: {input}
    })

    
    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;
  return products.results.map(({ id, name }) => (
    <div key={id}>
      <p>
        {name}
      </p>
    </div>
  ));
  };
```

My GET_PRODUTCS_QUERY look like this

```
const GET_PRODUTCS_QUERY = gql`
query getProducts ($name: String!){
  products( page: 1, filter: { name: $name })  {
    results {
      name,
      id
    }
  }
}
`;
```

I would like to trigger FetchProducts method when te value of my input text field will have more than 3 characters.
Something like this:

```
const triggerFetch = () => {
  input.length > 3 ? FetchProducts(input) : '';
};
```

This is a chunk from the JSX that I return on the my function component:

```
<input type="text" onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value), triggerFetch } value={input} placeholder="Search..."/>
```

I do not see where or how can I call the getProducts() function setup on the useLazyQuery hook

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? Kind of running into the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a LazyQuery with this code. You can implement it with a LazyQuery but you'll have to rework your code.

```
const FetchProducts = (input) => {
    
    const { data, loading, error } =  useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS_QUERY, {
      variables: {name: input}
    })

    
    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;
  return products.results.map(({ id, name }) => (
    <div key={id}>
      <p>
        {name}
      </p>
    </div>
  ));
  };
```

Comment: This will be executed while the component is mounted, thats why I need to use LazyQuery, I want to trigger the function once the valueof the input field is larger than 3 characters